# Turning shapefile into mask and calculating mean

Tags: python, gdal, masking

I have been using Python to process huge arrays stored as NetCDF files. I would like to calculate the mean of an area defined by a shapefile.
I have just installed GDAL but if there are other tools I should use please let me know.

So my main question is how can I turn my shapefile into a mask?

Then use my mask to calculate the NumPy mean of my array within the area of the mask?

```
shp="country.shp"
array=mynumpyarray
mask=useGDALtochangeshapefiletomask
meanofarea=N.mean(array,limits=mask)
```

---

I have been able to convert my shapefile to a raster using gdal_RasterizeLayer link supplied and then a masked array using

```
maskarray=mask_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

Now it is just a question of matching my NetCDF extent with my raster/maskarray. Here are my extents as requested.

```
my shapefile/raster extent: x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max 140.962408758 149.974994992 -39.1366533667 -33.9813898583

my netcdf file extent: min longitude: 139.8 max longitude: 150.0 min latitude -39.2 max latitude: -33.6 LAT size 106 LON size 193
```

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for the [gdal.RasterizeLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220749/rasterizing-a-gdal-layer) function.

You could then use ReadAsArray to turn the rasterized polygon into a numpy array.

Based on your NetCDF file extent and rows/columns, the following code should generate you a numpy 0-1 mask that matches the NetCDF exactly.

```
shapefile=r'whatever your shapefile path is'
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax=[139.8,-39.2,150.0,-33.6] #Your extents as given above
ncols,nrows=[193,106] #Your rows/cols as given above
maskvalue = 1

xres=(xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres=(ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)

src_ds = ogr.Open(shapefile)
src_lyr=src_ds.GetLayer()

dst_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Byte)
dst_rb = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
dst_rb.Fill(0) #initialise raster with zeros
dst_rb.SetNoDataValue(0)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(dst_ds, [1], src_lyr, burn_values=[maskvalue])

dst_ds.FlushCache()

mask_arr=dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to call [gdal_rasterize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) from within your Python code (use `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_call`), either using your NetCDF file as the destination, or create a separate image file (GeoTIFF is always a good bet) and load it into a numpy array. It may be possible to use GDAL's [In Memory Raster](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html) format, but I'm not sure what support there is for it in Python, and how it would play with numpy arrays.

There is an overhead with calling a subprocess and loading an image, but that will probably be amortized by the time it takes to do the actual rasterization.

If you want to roll your own, you could write a simple [scanline renderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanline_rendering), but I suspect that would be more fraught and possibly slower if written in pure Python.

Answer (score 5):

Now in 2017, I use `rasterio.mask.mask` and `fiona` to rasterize the shape file and then apply that to the netCDF dataset using `xarray`.

---

Now in 2019, there is https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray to ease the integration of `rasterio` and `xarray`. Clipping a dataset (e.g. from NetCDF) with a geometry is listed as example here: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html