# Rasterize GeoJSON or Shapely Geometry?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterization, rasterio

I am trying to rasterize a GeoJSON or shapely geometry but it does not rasterize all the geometry (some of it is not in the TIFF-file).

I tried `gdal_rasterize -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -ts 4950 4900 src destination` and also tried the `rasterize` function from rasterio. None of it is working.

Can someone explain how to get all the shapes in the raster?

Comment: Is none of it working, or some of it working?  Can you give an input GeoJSON and an output Raster example.

Comment: Some of it is working. Most polygons of the GeoJSON get rasterized.

Comment: I guess the real question is, how do I properly set the value of `ts`, `tr`, and `te`. I noticed I did not have `ALL_TOUCHED = True`. This seemed to include the missing polygons.

Comment: Your question needs more detail about the type of geometry you are attempting to rasterise (i.e. point, line, polygon and the multi* versions, or even collections of mixed geometries). There are idiosyncrasies there. However `ALL_TOCUHED` is probably all you need to get what you expect. Without it, the output raster only includes cells with their *centres* within the input vector features (for polygons). If so, this question is a clear duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31568/gdal-rasterizelayer-does-not-burn-all-polygons-to-raster?rq=1

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59270077/9977650?